# showing error as cannot convert value of type 'x'(i.e..,array model object) to expected type 'x' (i.e..,array model object)

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3

i have one switch and table.if the switch is "on" i should  include deactivated users if the switch is "off" then show only active customer.i am getting data from api as all customers based on response of api .In  that one parameter named  as active if active is true then the customer is active. for that
i am trying to copy data from one model to another model in swift showing error asshowing error as cannot convert value of type 'sguserdata'(i.e..,arraymodelobject) to expected argument type 'sguserwithoutactivationdeactivation' (i.e..,arraymodelobject) both array objects are similar except main name

```
import UIKit

  class SGUserlistViewController: SGBaseViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
var userlistdatawithmsg:sguserlistdatawithmsg?
@IBOutlet weak var usertable: UITableView!


@IBOutlet weak var btnnew_users: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var IncludeDeactiveview: UIView!


@IBOutlet weak var includedeactive_switch: UISwitch!
    let  activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 55, height: 55))
var userlistwithoutdeactivation : sguserlistdatawithoutdeactivation?
 var userdatawithoutdeactivation = [sguserwithoutdeactivation]()
 var userdata = [sguserdata]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.title = "Users"
    super.viewDidLoad()



    searchonlypending()
      self.usertable.register(UINib(nibName: "sgpurchaseorderviewallTableViewCell", bundle: Bundle.main), forCellReuseIdentifier: "sgpurchaseorderviewallTableViewCell")





}
func searchonlypending(){
    self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    let params: [String : Any] = [:]

           SGWebServices.sharedWebServices.getuserlist(params:params) { (error, response) in
        if (error == nil) {


            if response?.message != "Authorization has been denied for this request."{
                print("success")

                  let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
                   let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: response!)
                userDefaults.set(encodedData, forKey: "userlist")
                userDefaults.synchronize()
        //let userlist = self.userlistdatawithmsg?.data
                                self.usertable.reloadData()
                  self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                if  response?.data.count == 0{
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title:"" , message: "No User found", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))

                    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }

            }else{
                             self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SgloginViewController")
                self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
        else{


                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Oops", message: "Something went wrong", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))

                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)




            }
    }
}


@IBAction func addnewuser(_ sender: UIButton) {



    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SGAdduserViewController")
           self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if  includedeactive_switch.isOn == true{
    if  userlistwithoutdeactivation?.data.count != nil{

        return (userlistwithoutdeactivation?.data.count)!
    }
    }
    else{

        if  userlistwithoutdeactivation?.data.count != nil{
            return (userlistwithoutdeactivation?.data.count)!
        }



    }
    return 0

}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 91
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = usertable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "sgpurchaseorderviewallTableViewCell")! as! sgpurchaseorderviewallTableViewCell


    cell.poname.text = userlistwithoutdeactivation?.data[indexPath.row].userName
    cell.fromclient.text = userlistwithoutdeactivation?.data[indexPath.row].roleName


    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
    let selected_rowforuserdetails = indexPath.row
    print(selected_rowforuserdetails)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(selected_rowforuserdetails, forKey:"selected_row_for_userdetils")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SGUserdetailViewController")
    self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)





}

@IBAction func userlistincludedeactiveations(_ sender: UISwitch) {



    if includedeactive_switch.isOn == false{

                print(self.userlistdatawithmsg?.data.count)
    //let userlist = self.userlistdatawithmsg?.data
        if SGManager.sharedManager.getuserslist()?.data != nil{

            let modeldata =  SGManager.sharedManager.getuserslist()
          userlistdatawithmsg = modeldata

    for pom in (self.userlistdatawithmsg?.data)!{
        if  pom.active == true
        {

             self.userlistwithoutdeactivation?.data.append(pom)

        }
    }
     usertable.reloadData()
        }

    }
    else{

            print(self.userlistdatawithmsg?.data.count)
        if SGManager.sharedManager.getuserslist()?.data != nil{

            let modeldata =  SGManager.sharedManager.getuserslist()
            userlistdatawithmsg = modeldata
             self.userlistwithoutdeactivation?.data[0] = userlistdatawithmsg?.data[0]
                             usertable.reloadData()

        }


    }


}

 }
```

and the two models are simillar except their names

model 1:

```
 import Foundation


 class sguserdata : NSObject, NSCoding{

var active : Bool!
var billingAddress : AnyObject!
var clientId : Int!
var confirmPassword : AnyObject!
var createdByUserName : AnyObject!
var domainInfo : AnyObject!
var email : String!
var emailConfirmed : Bool!
var emailStatus : Bool!
var firstName : String!
var id : String!
var imagePath : AnyObject!
var joinDate : String!
var lastName : String!
var level : Int!
var loggedInUserClientId : Int!
var loggedInUserId : AnyObject!
var loggedInUserName : AnyObject!
var password : AnyObject!
var passwordHash : AnyObject!
var phoneNumber : String!
var role : sguserrole!
var roleId : AnyObject!
var roleName : String!
var securityStamp : AnyObject!
var userName : String!


/**
 * Instantiate the instance using the passed dictionary values to set the properties values
 */
init(fromDictionary dictionary: NSDictionary){
    active = dictionary["active"] as? Bool
    billingAddress = dictionary["billingAddress"] as? AnyObject
    clientId = dictionary["clientId"] as? Int
    confirmPassword = dictionary["confirmPassword"] as? AnyObject
    createdByUserName = dictionary["createdByUserName"] as? AnyObject
    domainInfo = dictionary["domainInfo"] as? AnyObject
    email = dictionary["email"] as? String
    emailConfirmed = dictionary["emailConfirmed"] as? Bool
    emailStatus = dictionary["emailStatus"] as? Bool
    firstName = dictionary["firstName"] as? String
    id = dictionary["id"] as? String
    imagePath = dictionary["imagePath"] as? AnyObject
    joinDate = dictionary["joinDate"] as? String
    lastName = dictionary["lastName"] as? String
    level = dictionary["level"] as? Int
    loggedInUserClientId = dictionary["loggedInUserClientId"] as? Int
    loggedInUserId = dictionary["loggedInUserId"] as? AnyObject
    loggedInUserName = dictionary["loggedInUserName"] as? AnyObject
    password = dictionary["password"] as? AnyObject
    passwordHash = dictionary["passwordHash"] as? AnyObject
    phoneNumber = dictionary["phoneNumber"] as? String
    if let roleData = dictionary["role"] as? NSDictionary{
        role = sguserrole(fromDictionary: roleData)
    }
    roleId = dictionary["roleId"] as? AnyObject
    roleName = dictionary["roleName"] as? String
    securityStamp = dictionary["securityStamp"] as? AnyObject
    userName = dictionary["userName"] as? String
}

/**
 * Returns all the available property values in the form of NSDictionary object where the key is the approperiate json key and the value is the value of the corresponding property
 */
func toDictionary() -> NSDictionary
{
    var dictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
    if active != nil{
        dictionary["active"] = active
    }
    if billingAddress != nil{
        dictionary["billingAddress"] = billingAddress
    }
    if clientId != nil{
        dictionary["clientId"] = clientId
    }
    if confirmPassword != nil{
        dictionary["confirmPassword"] = confirmPassword
    }
    if createdByUserName != nil{
        dictionary["createdByUserName"] = createdByUserName
    }
    if domainInfo != nil{
        dictionary["domainInfo"] = domainInfo
    }
    if email != nil{
        dictionary["email"] = email
    }
    if emailConfirmed != nil{
        dictionary["emailConfirmed"] = emailConfirmed
    }
    if emailStatus != nil{
        dictionary["emailStatus"] = emailStatus
    }
    if firstName != nil{
        dictionary["firstName"] = firstName
    }
    if id != nil{
        dictionary["id"] = id
    }
    if imagePath != nil{
        dictionary["imagePath"] = imagePath
    }
    if joinDate != nil{
        dictionary["joinDate"] = joinDate
    }
    if lastName != nil{
        dictionary["lastName"] = lastName
    }
    if level != nil{
        dictionary["level"] = level
    }
    if loggedInUserClientId != nil{
        dictionary["loggedInUserClientId"] = loggedInUserClientId
    }
    if loggedInUserId != nil{
        dictionary["loggedInUserId"] = loggedInUserId
    }
    if loggedInUserName != nil{
        dictionary["loggedInUserName"] = loggedInUserName
    }
    if password != nil{
        dictionary["password"] = password
    }
    if passwordHash != nil{
        dictionary["passwordHash"] = passwordHash
    }
    if phoneNumber != nil{
        dictionary["phoneNumber"] = phoneNumber
    }
    if role != nil{
        dictionary["role"] = role.toDictionary()
    }
    if roleId != nil{
        dictionary["roleId"] = roleId
    }
    if roleName != nil{
        dictionary["roleName"] = roleName
    }
    if securityStamp != nil{
        dictionary["securityStamp"] = securityStamp
    }
    if userName != nil{
        dictionary["userName"] = userName
    }
    return dictionary
}

/**
 * NSCoding required initializer.
 * Fills the data from the passed decoder
 */
@objc required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
    active = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "active") as? Bool
    billingAddress = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "billingAddress") as? AnyObject
    clientId = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "clientId") as? Int
    confirmPassword = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "confirmPassword") as? AnyObject
    createdByUserName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "createdByUserName") as? AnyObject
    domainInfo = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "domainInfo") as? AnyObject
    email = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "email") as? String
    emailConfirmed = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "emailConfirmed") as? Bool
    emailStatus = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "emailStatus") as? Bool
    firstName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "firstName") as? String
    id = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "id") as? String
    imagePath = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "imagePath") as? AnyObject
    joinDate = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "joinDate") as? String
    lastName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "lastName") as? String
    level = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "level") as? Int
    loggedInUserClientId = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "loggedInUserClientId") as? Int
    loggedInUserId = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "loggedInUserId") as? AnyObject
    loggedInUserName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "loggedInUserName") as? AnyObject
    password = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "password") as? AnyObject
    passwordHash = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "passwordHash") as? AnyObject
    phoneNumber = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "phoneNumber") as? String
    role = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "role") as? sguserrole
    roleId = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "roleId") as? AnyObject
    roleName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "roleName") as? String
    securityStamp = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "securityStamp") as? AnyObject
    userName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "userName") as? String

}

/**
 * NSCoding required method.
 * Encodes mode properties into the decoder
 */
 @objc func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder)
{
    if active != nil{
        aCoder.encode(active, forKey: "active")
    }
    if billingAddress != nil{
        aCoder.encode(billingAddress, forKey: "billingAddress")
    }
    if clientId != nil{
        aCoder.encode(clientId, forKey: "clientId")
    }
    if confirmPassword != nil{
        aCoder.encode(confirmPassword, forKey: "confirmPassword")
    }
    if createdByUserName != nil{
        aCoder.encode(createdByUserName, forKey: "createdByUserName")
    }
    if domainInfo != nil{
        aCoder.encode(domainInfo, forKey: "domainInfo")
    }
    if email != nil{
        aCoder.encode(email, forKey: "email")
    }
    if emailConfirmed != nil{
        aCoder.encode(emailConfirmed, forKey: "emailConfirmed")
    }
    if emailStatus != nil{
        aCoder.encode(emailStatus, forKey: "emailStatus")
    }
    if firstName != nil{
        aCoder.encode(firstName, forKey: "firstName")
    }
    if id != nil{
        aCoder.encode(id, forKey: "id")
    }
    if imagePath != nil{
        aCoder.encode(imagePath, forKey: "imagePath")
    }
    if joinDate != nil{
        aCoder.encode(joinDate, forKey: "joinDate")
    }
    if lastName != nil{
        aCoder.encode(lastName, forKey: "lastName")
    }
    if level != nil{
        aCoder.encode(level, forKey: "level")
    }
    if loggedInUserClientId != nil{
        aCoder.encode(loggedInUserClientId, forKey: "loggedInUserClientId")
    }
    if loggedInUserId != nil{
        aCoder.encode(loggedInUserId, forKey: "loggedInUserId")
    }
    if loggedInUserName != nil{
        aCoder.encode(loggedInUserName, forKey: "loggedInUserName")
    }
    if password != nil{
        aCoder.encode(password, forKey: "password")
    }
    if passwordHash != nil{
        aCoder.encode(passwordHash, forKey: "passwordHash")
    }
    if phoneNumber != nil{
        aCoder.encode(phoneNumber, forKey: "phoneNumber")
    }
    if role != nil{
        aCoder.encode(role, forKey: "role")
    }
    if roleId != nil{
        aCoder.encode(roleId, forKey: "roleId")
    }
    if roleName != nil{
        aCoder.encode(roleName, forKey: "roleName")
    }
    if securityStamp != nil{
        aCoder.encode(securityStamp, forKey: "securityStamp")
    }
    if userName != nil{
        aCoder.encode(userName, forKey: "userName")
    }

}
```

}

model 2:

```
   import Foundation


  class sguserwithoutdeactivation : NSObject, NSCoding{

var active : Bool!
var billingAddress : AnyObject!
var clientId : Int!
var confirmPassword : AnyObject!
var createdByUserName : AnyObject!
var domainInfo : AnyObject!
var email : String!
var emailConfirmed : Bool!
var emailStatus : Bool!
var firstName : String!
var id : String!
var imagePath : AnyObject!
var joinDate : String!
var lastName : String!
var level : Int!
var loggedInUserClientId : Int!
var loggedInUserId : AnyObject!
var loggedInUserName : AnyObject!
var password : AnyObject!
var passwordHash : AnyObject!
var phoneNumber : String!
var role : sguserrole!
var roleId : AnyObject!
var roleName : String!
var securityStamp : AnyObject!
var userName : String!


/**
 * Instantiate the instance using the passed dictionary values to set the properties values
 */
init(fromDictionary dictionary: NSDictionary){
    active = dictionary["active"] as? Bool
    billingAddress = dictionary["billingAddress"] as? AnyObject
    clientId = dictionary["clientId"] as? Int
    confirmPassword = dictionary["confirmPassword"] as? AnyObject
    createdByUserName = dictionary["createdByUserName"] as? AnyObject
    domainInfo = dictionary["domainInfo"] as? AnyObject
    email = dictionary["email"] as? String
    emailConfirmed = dictionary["emailConfirmed"] as? Bool
    emailStatus = dictionary["emailStatus"] as? Bool
    firstName = dictionary["firstName"] as? String
    id = dictionary["id"] as? String
    imagePath = dictionary["imagePath"] as? AnyObject
    joinDate = dictionary["joinDate"] as? String
    lastName = dictionary["lastName"] as? String
    level = dictionary["level"] as? Int
    loggedInUserClientId = dictionary["loggedInUserClientId"] as? Int
    loggedInUserId = dictionary["loggedInUserId"] as? AnyObject
    loggedInUserName = dictionary["loggedInUserName"] as? AnyObject
    password = dictionary["password"] as? AnyObject
    passwordHash = dictionary["passwordHash"] as? AnyObject
    phoneNumber = dictionary["phoneNumber"] as? String
    if let roleData = dictionary["role"] as? NSDictionary{
        role = sguserrole(fromDictionary: roleData)
    }
    roleId = dictionary["roleId"] as? AnyObject
    roleName = dictionary["roleName"] as? String
    securityStamp = dictionary["securityStamp"] as? AnyObject
    userName = dictionary["userName"] as? String
}

/**
 * Returns all the available property values in the form of NSDictionary object where the key is the approperiate json key and the value is the value of the corresponding property
 */
func toDictionary() -> NSDictionary
{
    var dictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
    if active != nil{
        dictionary["active"] = active
    }
    if billingAddress != nil{
        dictionary["billingAddress"] = billingAddress
    }
    if clientId != nil{
        dictionary["clientId"] = clientId
    }
    if confirmPassword != nil{
        dictionary["confirmPassword"] = confirmPassword
    }
    if createdByUserName != nil{
        dictionary["createdByUserName"] = createdByUserName
    }
    if domainInfo != nil{
        dictionary["domainInfo"] = domainInfo
    }
    if email != nil{
        dictionary["email"] = email
    }
    if emailConfirmed != nil{
        dictionary["emailConfirmed"] = emailConfirmed
    }
    if emailStatus != nil{
        dictionary["emailStatus"] = emailStatus
    }
    if firstName != nil{
        dictionary["firstName"] = firstName
    }
    if id != nil{
        dictionary["id"] = id
    }
    if imagePath != nil{
        dictionary["imagePath"] = imagePath
    }
    if joinDate != nil{
        dictionary["joinDate"] = joinDate
    }
    if lastName != nil{
        dictionary["lastName"] = lastName
    }
    if level != nil{
        dictionary["level"] = level
    }
    if loggedInUserClientId != nil{
        dictionary["loggedInUserClientId"] = loggedInUserClientId
    }
    if loggedInUserId != nil{
        dictionary["loggedInUserId"] = loggedInUserId
    }
    if loggedInUserName != nil{
        dictionary["loggedInUserName"] = loggedInUserName
    }
    if password != nil{
        dictionary["password"] = password
    }
    if passwordHash != nil{
        dictionary["passwordHash"] = passwordHash
    }
    if phoneNumber != nil{
        dictionary["phoneNumber"] = phoneNumber
    }
    if role != nil{
        dictionary["role"] = role.toDictionary()
    }
    if roleId != nil{
        dictionary["roleId"] = roleId
    }
    if roleName != nil{
        dictionary["roleName"] = roleName
    }
    if securityStamp != nil{
        dictionary["securityStamp"] = securityStamp
    }
    if userName != nil{
        dictionary["userName"] = userName
    }
    return dictionary
}

/**
 * NSCoding required initializer.
 * Fills the data from the passed decoder
 */
@objc required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
    active = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "active") as? Bool
    billingAddress = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "billingAddress") as? AnyObject
    clientId = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "clientId") as? Int
    confirmPassword = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "confirmPassword") as? AnyObject
    createdByUserName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "createdByUserName") as? AnyObject
    domainInfo = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "domainInfo") as? AnyObject
    email = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "email") as? String
    emailConfirmed = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "emailConfirmed") as? Bool
    emailStatus = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "emailStatus") as? Bool
    firstName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "firstName") as? String
    id = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "id") as? String
    imagePath = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "imagePath") as? AnyObject
    joinDate = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "joinDate") as? String
    lastName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "lastName") as? String
    level = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "level") as? Int
    loggedInUserClientId = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "loggedInUserClientId") as? Int
    loggedInUserId = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "loggedInUserId") as? AnyObject
    loggedInUserName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "loggedInUserName") as? AnyObject
    password = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "password") as? AnyObject
    passwordHash = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "passwordHash") as? AnyObject
    phoneNumber = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "phoneNumber") as? String
    role = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "role") as? sguserrole
    roleId = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "roleId") as? AnyObject
    roleName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "roleName") as? String
    securityStamp = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "securityStamp") as? AnyObject
    userName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "userName") as? String

}

/**
 * NSCoding required method.
 * Encodes mode properties into the decoder
 */
@objc func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder)
{
    if active != nil{
        aCoder.encode(active, forKey: "active")
    }
    if billingAddress != nil{
        aCoder.encode(billingAddress, forKey: "billingAddress")
    }
    if clientId != nil{
        aCoder.encode(clientId, forKey: "clientId")
    }
    if confirmPassword != nil{
        aCoder.encode(confirmPassword, forKey: "confirmPassword")
    }
    if createdByUserName != nil{
        aCoder.encode(createdByUserName, forKey: "createdByUserName")
    }
    if domainInfo != nil{
        aCoder.encode(domainInfo, forKey: "domainInfo")
    }
    if email != nil{
        aCoder.encode(email, forKey: "email")
    }
    if emailConfirmed != nil{
        aCoder.encode(emailConfirmed, forKey: "emailConfirmed")
    }
    if emailStatus != nil{
        aCoder.encode(emailStatus, forKey: "emailStatus")
    }
    if firstName != nil{
        aCoder.encode(firstName, forKey: "firstName")
    }
    if id != nil{
        aCoder.encode(id, forKey: "id")
    }
    if imagePath != nil{
        aCoder.encode(imagePath, forKey: "imagePath")
    }
    if joinDate != nil{
        aCoder.encode(joinDate, forKey: "joinDate")
    }
    if lastName != nil{
        aCoder.encode(lastName, forKey: "lastName")
    }
    if level != nil{
        aCoder.encode(level, forKey: "level")
    }
    if loggedInUserClientId != nil{
        aCoder.encode(loggedInUserClientId, forKey: "loggedInUserClientId")
    }
    if loggedInUserId != nil{
        aCoder.encode(loggedInUserId, forKey: "loggedInUserId")
    }
    if loggedInUserName != nil{
        aCoder.encode(loggedInUserName, forKey: "loggedInUserName")
    }
    if password != nil{
        aCoder.encode(password, forKey: "password")
    }
    if passwordHash != nil{
        aCoder.encode(passwordHash, forKey: "passwordHash")
    }
    if phoneNumber != nil{
        aCoder.encode(phoneNumber, forKey: "phoneNumber")
    }
    if role != nil{
        aCoder.encode(role, forKey: "role")
    }
    if roleId != nil{
        aCoder.encode(roleId, forKey: "roleId")
    }
    if roleName != nil{
        aCoder.encode(roleName, forKey: "roleName")
    }
    if securityStamp != nil{
        aCoder.encode(securityStamp, forKey: "securityStamp")
    }
    if userName != nil{
        aCoder.encode(userName, forKey: "userName")
    }

 }

 }
```

please help if anyone know the solution.

Comment: What is the purpose of using two separate classes with the same content?

Comment: as i said i had switch if user is selected include deactive then some dat will be missing so far that i am doing like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I recommend starting class names with a capital letter, it makes your code much easier to read.

To solve your problem I would make a protocol containing all the common fields you want to show and then make both classes conform to that protocol. Then you can have an array of that protocol in your viewcontroller and you can populate it with members of either class.

```
protocol SGUserType {
var active: Bool { get set }
var billingAddress: Any { get set }
...
}

class SGUserData : SGUserType, NSObject, NSCoding {
var active: Bool
var billingAddress: Any
...
}
```

So in your viewcontroller instead of having:

```
var userlistwithoutdeactivation : sguserlistdatawithoutdeactivation?
var userdatawithoutdeactivation = [sguserwithoutdeactivation]()
var userdata = [sguserdata]()
```

You can have:

```
var userData = [SGUserType]()
```

Comment: how to use that.

Comment: please elobrate ur answer and  explain how to use

Comment: I assume the error you get happens in this line:
    self.userlistwithoutdeactivation?.data.append(pom)

This is because you try to add data of one type to an array of another type. If both your classes conform to the same protocol you can specify your array as being of that type and then you can add both types to it.

Comment: when adding like this show error as   import Foundation

protocol SGUserType {
 
    var active : Bool!
    var billingAddress : AnyObject!
    var clientId : Int!
    var confirmPassword : AnyObject!
    var createdByUserName : AnyObject!
    }class sguserdata :  NSObject, SGUserType, NSCoding{
    
    var active : Bool!
    var billingAddress : AnyObject!
    var clientId : Int!
    var confirmPassword : AnyObject!
    var createdByUserName : AnyObject!
showing error as 
 Property in protocol must have explicit { get } or { get set } specifier

Comment: after adding protocol still it is showing the error  Cannot convert value of type 'sguserdata' to expected argument type 'sguserwithoutdeactivation'